# Draw HTML table border

Tags: asp.net, css

I want to draw the border of my table on a HTML page :

**HTML** :

```
<asp:Table>
    <asp:TableRow CssClass="columnHeader">
        <asp:TableCell BorderWidth="0px" BackColor="White"></asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="3" ><asp:Label ID="lbl_Dimension" runat="server" >Dimension in CM</asp:Label></asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="2" ><asp:Label ID="lbl_Weight" runat="server" >Weight in KG</asp:Label></asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell ><asp:Label ID="lbl_Volume" runat="server" >Volume</asp:Label></asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableRow CssClass="columnHeader">
        <asp:TableCell BorderWidth="0px" BackColor="White"></asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell ><asp:Label /></asp:TableCell> (x6)
    </asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell CssClass="rowHeader"><asp:Label ID="lbl_Pallet" runat="server" >Pallet</asp:Label></asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell ><asp:Label /></asp:TableCell> (x6)
    </asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableRow >
        <asp:TableCell CssClass="rowHeader"><asp:Label ID="lbl_Master" runat="server" >Master</asp:Label></asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell ><asp:Label /></asp:TableCell> (x6)
    </asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell CssClass="rowHeader"><asp:Label ID="lbl_Inner" runat="server" >Inner</asp:Label></asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell ><asp:Label /></asp:TableCell> (x6)
    </asp:TableRow>  
</asp:Table>
```

**CSS** :

```
.drawBorder table
{
    border: 0 solid Black;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin-top: 30px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.drawBorder th, .drawBorder td
{
    border: 1px solid Black;
    width: 80px;
}
.rowHeader
{
    background-color: #f4e8d0;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.columnHeader
{   
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f4e8d0;
    border: 1px solid Black;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**Result on IE** :

[image]

**Result on Chrome** :

[image]

So... Two questions :

- Why IE doesn't do the `ColSpan` on my first row ?
- Why the `border-collapse: collapse;` doesn't work ?

(I don't write my complete HTML code because I can't post mostly code message...)

Comment: your table is all wrong - the number of columns don't match for each row in the table

Comment: I wrote on the bottom of the post that I don't have post all my HTML code, I can say to you that my columns count is the same on each row ;)

Comment: Right then you said html code not asp code there is a big difference and you've addded the x6 after I commented

Comment: Yeah, you're right, but my asp components are translate as HTML component by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I created this fiddle based on your scenario: http://jsfiddle.net/YVEsJ/1/

It looks just the same on IE and Chrome. The `border-collapse` works as intended.

The reason you are getting unintended results may be because of some extra css style somewhere. Start from the fiddle I linked above and then work your way upwards on your styles.

Better still, I would suggest you create a plain HTML `table` instead of a server-side control (asp:table). This is because the server-side controls spit out extra HTML attributes which may override your css. Use server-side controls inside the cells for labels if required. Better still use plain `span` with `runat="server"`.

Comment: Got it, thanks, you put me on the right way ! I set the `border-collapse: collapse;` on the `<table></table>` and I have cut the `width: 80px;` in the `.drawBorder th, td` class for the colspan. And now all work fine. Thanks again !

Comment: Glad to be of help. :)